# How to find value of an analytic function at a particular value given some conditions?

Tags: complex-analysis

I've come across a question from gate 2018 paper.Not able to come up with solution,can somebody give some idea to solve this.

Let f : C → C be an entire function with f(0) = 1, f(1) = 2 and f′(0) = 0. If there exists
M > 0 such that |f′′(z)| ≤ M for all z ∈ C, then f(2) =
(A) 2 (B) 5 (C) 2 + 5i (D) 5 + 2i

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you had the condition $|f(z)|\le M$ for all $M$, then $f$ would be a constant, by Liouville. But you don't have that, you have $|f''(z)|\le M$. What does this tell you about $f$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f(z)$ is entire, so is $f''(z)$; since $\vert f''(z) \vert < M$, by Liouville's theorem $f''(z)$ is constant:

$f''(z) = a \in \Bbb C; \tag 1$

then we have

$f(z) = \dfrac{1}{2}az^2 + bz + c, \; b, c \in \Bbb C; \tag 2$

thus

$f'(z) = az + b; \tag 3$

we now use the given data

$f(0) = 1, \; f(1) = 2, \; f'(0) = 0 \tag 4$

and find that

$c = 1, \dfrac{1}{2}a + b + c = 2, \; b = 0; \tag 5$

together these give

$a = 2, \tag 6$

whence

$f(z) = z^2 + 1; \tag 7$

thus,

$f(2) = 5, \tag 8$

and so (B) is correct.